# Database Management Systems, how to make multiple records belong to multiple other records

Tags: database, postgresql

I know the wording of the question is a bit tricky, so I will try to make it more understandable.

I have a table of Exercises, a table of Workouts, and a table of Users.

Exercises have their IDs, names, sets, repetitions and weight.

Workouts have their IDs, names, difficulty, duration, and resting times.

Users have Logins and a lot of irrelevant stuff.

At the moment, I have a lot of SAME exercises with different ID's, with a foreign key leading to Workout ID. So my tables look very messy. For example, there are 3 exercises "Bench Press", all the same, just the ID's that link to different Workouts are different. Same goes for workouts, a lot of the same ones, just different ID.

My question is, how can I create tables, where multiple records (Exercises) could belong to multiple records in a different table (Workouts), or how can I create two tables where multiple exercises can be at the same time present in multiple workouts, and the same exercise can appear in multiple Workouts.

Comment: Use junction tables. The idea is to model your database such that relationships are entities of their own. This way you just add more relationships that point to the same pairs of entities rather than replicating your entities.

Comment: Think of each table as it's own object. You have your exercise, workouts, and users objects. Each should be distinct in their table to hold their distinct attributes, but their relationship to one another shouldn't be present. The relationships are, seperately, their own object. So an ExerciseWorkout table and a WorkoutUser table can then store the ids. `ExerciseID | WorkoutID` for instance. Relationships, themselves, have attributes. Often `validFrom | validTo` or `lastChangedBy`, etc.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with Nevill.

Exercise Table
Workout Table
User Table
UserExercise Table
UserWorkout Table

So users can be tied to Exercises with the UserExercise table - ExerciseID and UserID would be stored there- giving you a a link of Users to Exercises.  Same for the UserWorkout table. Obviously you need to adapt to fit your use case(s).

You do want to establish and document the relationships in your UserWorkout Table, with Foreign Key definitions (FK's). This says that ExerciseID belongs to the Exercise table, ID attribute - the Primary Key (PK) of the table.

This is the relational model at work. You don't duplicate data that way, and you can use Joins and views to make friendly views into the relational tables.